# Synchronized method Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have a question about synchronization between threads.

Indeed, I have a method that only reads a static variable. Some threads access to this variable but there are no writing, only reading.

Do I have to declare the method Synchonized ?

Comment: No. There is no point of declaring a read operation as synchronized

Comment: is this a constant? how does it get initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization is an issue for ordering the threads together when accessing a resource in read and write mode.

If the value is not modified, then **it's useless to mark the assessor to this variable as synchronized**.

Nevertheless, returning the internal representation of a been's property could be damaging in case the variable is an object because you return the reference to this object.

So even if it's a read, nothing prevent the code to change the value later..

That's why some bug tracking tools warns you when you returns an internal reference of mutable objects.

Some are not mutable by nature like the Strings, the integers .... and all the primitives ( always passed by value).

What you can do to prevent mutability of your been, is to make a copy of the variable before returning it if this variable is a mutable type.

For example, you need to return the value of the myDate field:

```
private Date myDate;

public Date getMyDate(){
  // returning a copy of the myDate variable
  return (this.mydate==null)?null:new Date(this.mydate.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to make your method `synchronized`, but there should be a synchronization mechanism in place if you are using some variable (static or not) from multiple threads.

- If you are initializing the variable just once, you should be OK with just ensuring [safe publication](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/).

  - If the initialization can be racy, you should use a well-proven idiom like Double-Checked Locking (written correctly) or Initialization On Demand.
- If occasional writes to the variable are expected, you should eliminate opportunities for data races. You should ensure atomicity of the writes and visibility of these writes to the readers.

  - One common way to do this is to write through a `synchronized` method, make the variable `volatile`, and in case the variable is a complex object, ensure safe publication of its fields.

Comment: If thread A updates some variable, `v`, from within a `synchronized(o)` block, that is _not_ sufficient to establish a "happens before" relationship with some other thread B that reads `v`.   The most conventional way to establish happens-before would be for thread B to only read `v` from within another `synchronized(o)` block.

Comment: @jameslarge you're correct, but I'm not sure if your point is related to my answer in any way. Writing in a `synchronized` block and reading through a `volatile` field is a valid synchronization mechanism that suits a fair number of read-dominated use-cases. See what Brian Goetz calls the "cheap read-write lock" here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp06197/

Comment: Oops!  I did not read the whole sentence:  "One common way to do this is to write through a synchronized method, _make the variable volatile_, and..."  Sorry.

Comment: Unnecessary use of "volatile" is bad practice because "volatile" is expensive

Comment: @penguin that's a mostly correct statement, but it doesn't really clarify, correct or relate to the answer above or to my reply to @jameslarge, and that may be confusing to readers because I haven't recommended use of `volatile` where it will be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

When nothing setting a new value to the variable, you should be fine without having them synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a clear no. Not necessary and would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

> there are no writing, only reading.

Then there is **no need** for `synchronization`.

**However**, you should consider making static variable `final` as you already said it is used for only reading purpose. This step will guarantee protection from any possible concurrency hazard in future.